# angularjs and phonegap on windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, angularjs, cordova

I'm having trouble getting angularjs working on windows phone 7 with phonegap. The simple stiff works, but as soon as I try to add page include or a view (route) it doesn't do anything.  In the function matchUrl(url,obj) in angular.js (1.0.3) there is a regex that fails because Windows Phone use an unusual URL format.

What happens is angular is expecting a url like `'http://localhost/www/index.html'` but in windows phone it will look like: `'x-wmapp0:app/www/index.html'` instead.

Has anyone run across this and is there a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is as of now still unresolved and tracked here
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2303

EDIT:
The mentioned issue is still open although fix was submitted.

I managed to get a basic angular app running in phonegap WP7 by

1. applying the mentioned fix
2. including jquery (2.0.3) above angular.js
3. changing line of code in angular from

   var xhr = new XHR();

to

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

1. manually bootstrapping angular app after cordova deviceready event fired

I reported it [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4288)

Answer (score 0):

Using angularjs-1.1.5 and changing line 5612 with

```
var SERVER_MATCH = /^([^:]+):[\/\/]*(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\{?[\w\.-]*\}?)(:([0-9]+))?(\/[^\?#]*)?(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?$/,
```

should fix the problem

Comment: It doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: The problem is the regular expression with 'x-wampp0:' This change pass the url check. Why doesn't work for you?

Comment: I managed to make it work. It needed some other changes as-well. I will write up a blogpost in the next couple of days and link it here.